# Zend_Form: Newbie with non-standard form. Should I still use Zend_Form?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

***!!! UPDATED !!!***

We have spreadsheets of complex product data coming in from multiple sources (internal, customers, vendors).
Since the authorship is so diverse, it's impractical to try governing formatting details such as column order and the number of header-rows.

These CSV spreadsheets will be uploaded to our DB via an existing form.
(My first Zend_Form ... I'm almost done with it)

The user needs to see a sample from a given spreadsheet so they can Map the columns and start-row.
To achieve that,  I need to generate an html table of that dynamic content, and weave the form elements in and around the table data.
The user would select which values are to be found in each column, and identify the first row of data (after any header rows).
[**CLICK HERE**](http://voyagercomponents.com/download/test.html) to see an example.
(NOTE: Most of my work here is under an NDA, so contrived examples is the best we can get :)
In this example, I'd expect the output to be:

```
_POST('first_row'=>2, 'column0'=>'mi', 'column1'=>'lName', 'column2'=>'fName', 'column3'=>'gender')
```

With all those scpecifics mapped/defined, the uploaded spreadsheet can then be parsed and accurate data can be added to the product_history database.

Is ZF a good tool for this particular problem, or should I just write something from scratch?
How would ***you*** aproach this?
I am finally *JUST BARELY* starting to get this ZF stuff straight in my head, and this one has got me totally lost :)

Any and All advice appreciated.
~ Mo

Comment: What's the output expected from your example form? Could you give us a concrete example please.

Comment: I don't get it! The form seems to be pointless at this moment. Perhaps you could provide a more fleshed out example so the idea in your head make sense to others?

Comment: What, can't read my mind ??? ;) ... Users will be uploading CSV spreadsheets with complex product data. These SS's come from various sources (internal, customers, vendors) so column order and count of header-rows varies HUGELY ... For each upload, I need to show the user a sample of records from the SS so they can "map" the col's and the start row ... in my (slightly updated) example, the user would specify the starting row (3rd) and which col's are used for First, MI, Last, & Gender ... with that spec'd, I can cleanly parse values, & import ACCURATE info into our DB ... What questions remain?

Comment: Oh, yeah, and expected output would be:
    _POST('first_row'=>2, 'column0'=>'mi', 'column1'=>'lName', 'column2'=>'fName', 'column3'=>'gender')

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case, using Zend_Form would be helpful for this situation.

The tricky part to it is of course that your forms are going to be largely dynamically generated on-the-fly based on the header and first row content of the CSV file.

Whether you used Zend_Form, or pure PHP, or some other solution, a lot of what you will be doing is the same (analyzing the CSV, providing dynamic inputs based on the CSV, and then error checking the selections).  I think using Zend_Form has the advantage of making something like this very cleanly.

Given Zend_Form's nature, e.g. how it validates existing forms based on the elements added to the Zend_Form itself, you need to take a special approach with the form.  Basically, after the user uploads the CSV once, you will create a Zend_Form object based on the number of columns, their positions in the CSV, and the name of the column.

Since you don't want to bother the user to upload the CSV multiple times if they make incorrect selections, I would parse the CSV into some sort of structure, maybe a simple object or array, and then build your Zend_Form based on that data.  This way, you can save that structure to the session, so you can continue to regenerate the form based on the parsed data without having to read the file each time.  This is because the main challenge with Zend_Form and dynamic forms, is that not only does the form need all of the elements and their properties when you want to display the form, but they are also required in order to validate the form and re-display the validated form.

I remember seeing this functionality many years ago in a PHP script, which I found is still available.  Perhaps you could look at it for ideas.  I won't post the link here since the screenshots and script are mostly adult website related and the site is NSFW for the most part, but it is called TGPX by JMBSoft.  The 7th of the 8th screenshot on the main product page shows the import process where it lets the user map fields to data, exactly what you are doing.

Hope my advice is helpful, feel free to comment with any questions.

Comment: Thanks-a-bunch! ... your post provided a much needed search term -- "Zend_Form dynamic forms" ... Google is turning up a BUNCH with that ... I'll see what I can learn from there ... again, thanks!